# Large matlab plot doesnt display properly when using colours

Tags: matlab, colors, bar-chart

I have a large amount of data which I have plotted on a bar chart. The default is that the bars are all blue *with no spaces*. However when I try to add colours white lines appear on the solid blocks of colour. Why is this and is there a way to get rid of them?

```
n=3000
mydata=2-abs(randn(n,1));
x=zeros(n,1);

x(1:2*n/10)=1;
x(2*n/10+1:n/2)=2;
x(n/2 +1:6*n/10)=3;
x(6*n/10 +1:8*n /10)=4;
x(8*n/10 :n)=5;

data=[x,mydata];

data=sortrows(data,[1,2])

bar=bar(data(:,2));
bar_child=get(bar,'Children');
set(bar_child,'CData',data(:,1));
set(gca,'ytick',[])
set(bar_child, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

You can see the difference clearly if you try running it without the last 4 lines

```
 bar_child=get(bar,'Children');
 set(bar_child,'CData',data(:,1));
 set(gca,'ytick',[])
 set(bar_child, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - when you run the above without the last four lines, all bars are blue and you can't see any vertical white lines separating in the plot.  However, if you zoom in, you can start to see the white lines.  So they are there in other plot, just not as noticeable.

I'm not sure why this is happening.  More vertical white lines appear as I resize the multi-colour plot.

A workaround is as follows.  Since the default bar width is 0.8, change this to 1.0 so that there is no separation between bars

```
bar=bar(data(:,2),'BarWidth',1);
```

and re-run all lines of code.  When I did this, the results looked fine (no vertical white lines).

Try this and see what happens!